# How can i remove bitnami symbol and link from odoo pages?

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

Odoo 8 - We are installed odoo 8 in aws 2 server using bitnami

we got the bitnami symbol and link in my odoo pages

how can remove the bitnami from my odoo 8 ??

if u know please share ur valuable suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find how to remove the Bitnami button at https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Bitnami_info_page I hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your valuable suggestion but in your link this the solution  sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/discourse/bnconfig --disable_banner 1  but we don't have discourse directory                   http://i.imgur.com/pcKTmZa.png this is my page

Comment: Discourse is only an example, you should use "oddo" for the command.